# info about WCF and ASYNC

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, async-await

I am busy creating a WCF Web Service, that needs an ASYNC call. I have done this so far:

```
public async Task<bool> sendData(Data data) {
    bool sent = await Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        return someNameSpace.ReceiveData(data);
    });

    return sent;
}
```

So my question is, does the call to the dll also need to be marked as async?

ie. within the dll

```
public async Task<bool> ReceiveData(Data data) {
    // some async code
    // some code here
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may find my [`async`/`await` intro helpful](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). I also have a post specifically dealing with [`async` WCF](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/08/async-wcf-today-and-tomorrow.html).

Some general points:

- Don't use `StartNew` (or `Task.Run`) unless you explicitly want to run some code on a background thread.
- You can await any `Task`, regardless of where it came from. A method that returns a `Task` may or may not be `async` - it only makes a difference *within* that method.

So, if your `ReceiveData` is either of these (they look the same to `SendData`):

```
public async Task<bool> ReceiveData(Data data);
public Task<bool> ReceiveData(Data data);
```

Then you can just `await` it in `SendData`:

```
public async Task<bool> SendData(Data data)
{
  bool sent = await someNameSpace.ReceiveData(data);
  ... // do other stuff
  return sent;
}
```

Comment: You may find this useful about distributed transactions in WCF when using async/await as well: https://youtu.be/B-Q3T5KpiYk